# Is atmosphere meteor the same as meteor

Tags: grails, meteor, grails-plugin

I am very excited about meteor (@ meteor.com). But the project that I am working on is already deeply invested in Grails. So, I have been searching for examples of Grails projects that use Meteor. I just ran across the Grails plugin called "atmosphere meteor". Is this by any chance related to Meteor (@ meteor.com) ? They both talk about coordinating multiple web sites and a client-server model.

Answer (score 1):

Atmosphere is the official package ecosystem for Meteor 1.x, all javascript, running on the client browser and under node on the server. Meteor and Meteorite have been merged. Visit www.meteor.com and atmospherejs.com for more details.

The "atmosphere meteor" plugin for Grails has nothing to do with the Meteor Framework. It's about building async web apps through servlet support, a decidedly Java-opinionated perspective.

The two are quite different, and don't have anything to do with each other. Strictly unrelated.

Answer (score 0):

Atmosphere is the (currently unofficial) package ecosystem for Meteor, using the (currently unofficial) package manager Meteorite.

Both Grails and Meteor are designed to be full stack frameworks, for different languages. It will be very, very difficult to integrate the two. You're much better off starting from scratch with Meteor.

Edit: It appears what you're talking about is the Atmosphere Framework, which is not Meteor.